# What are non-linear differential equations used to model?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking for an example of their use.  What are some of the main applications of Bernoulli equations, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get a non-linear ODE (probably) in the solution process of some of [these](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nonlinear_partial_differential_equations#section_2) PDEs. they may not be Bernoulli ODEs though.